# Is there another way of renaming a file other than using mv?

Tags: linux, unix

I was wondering is there another way of renaming a file aside from using `mv` in linux?

For example changing `/home/usr/blah.txt` to something like `-home-usr-blah.txt`

Comment: You mean, you want to encode the path in the filename?

Comment: You could use `cp` and `rm`, but what's the point?

Comment: Your question does not make sense. What has renaming a file got to do with it's path?

Comment: @Tony: erm... Clueless? `ln` associates another _path_ with an existing _inode_. `unlink` dis-associates one of the associated paths from an _inode_. `touch newfile` creates a new inode with associated path `newfile`. _inodes_ are reference counted, i.e.: storage is reclaimed after the last referring path is unlinked.  What _else_ does it have to do with? Filesystems might implement this differently, but if they are POSIX compliant, the end result is exactly the same ([google POSIX rename](http://www.google.com/search?&q=posix+(mv+OR+rename)))

Answer (score 6):

This goes to show that you need to think about how you ask the question. Everybody - including me - got your question wrong initially

You could use qmv to bulk rename interactively using an editor. It will allow search/replace and also cyclic renames.

---

Simple

What mv really accomplishes at the driver level is close to this:

```
ln source target
unlink source
```

So, you can do that. This, however assumes the optimized scenario where source & target reside in the same filesystem. If not, you will have to use cp instead of ln. Be sure to make that a `cp -a`

Update in response to (paranoid) comment:

```
(ln source target || cp -a source target) && unlink source
```

---

Comment: This is a dangerous solution to program into a script though because it could result in data loss in the event that "ln" creates a symbolic link instead of a hard link.  It's great that you hint at this, but I do think it would be better to highlight this danger before that excellent two-command example.  (Unfortunately, "ln" doesn't appear to have a switch like -s but that ONLY succeeds if a hardlink is successfully created.)

Comment: @Randolf Richardson: Huh. Why the FUD? `ln` will never create a symbolic link unless told to. You might have a broken system or badly devised aliases working against you. Linux evidence: `ln dirname dirname2` --> `hard link not allowed for directory`; `ln ~/.bashrc /tmp/` --> `ln: creating hard link '/tmp/.bashrc' => '.bashrc': Invalid cross-device link`

Comment: Okay, thanks for pointing that out.  I must've been using a broken system before (there definitely wasn't an intention at FUD -- that's an area that a certain company which-shall-not-be-named has cornered the market on, and I have no interest in competing with them as they are specialists in that area and probably can't be beat at dispersing FUD).

Answer (score 3):

also hardlinks can be used for renaming files

```
[ 22:16:50 ~/Desktop ] $ echo 'hello' > myfile
[ 22:16:52 ~/Desktop ] $ ln myfile mynewfile
[ 22:17:04 ~/Desktop ] $ rm myfile
remove myfile? y
[ 22:17:11 ~/Desktop ] $ cat mynewfile
hello
[ 22:17:15 ~/Desktop ] $
```

Comment: Why would you do that instead of simply `mv myfile mynewfile`?

Comment: When transfering a file between two non-root accounts. The first user is responsible for doing the "ln". The second user is responsible for doing the "rm".

Answer (score 2):

Well, there is `rename`

But if you want to rename a full path into a single filename you will need to use other tools like `sed` or `awk`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use "rename" feature in various file management tools like Midnight Commander to do this, or you could use the `rename()` function from a Perl script (or equivilant functions with other programming/scripting languages).